# Is there any way to save the current user state of an android application

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nullpointerexception

In my app i have two login buttons one for teacher another for student , two logins redirect to an activity where firebase google sign in is added, i want to differentiate the users from which login they logged in to the app. I need your help in this..

Try 1:
I have used an additional variable state which passes the user and passed it using intent and after checking the data from the intent the welcome screen is loaded.
But in this case the variable is null after restarting the app as it takes directly to the welcome activity not from the login screen.

Try 2:
I used firestore to store the variable state and retrieve on restart but it retrives null from the database but the in Firebase console the data is there.
The task.getResult() produces a null pointer Exception.

**Fetching Databse where NullPointerException occurs in task.getResult() in for loop condition**

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("UserState")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d("ONSUCCESS", "Query Document Snapshot fetched successfully");
                            if (user != null) {
                                user = document.get("USER").toString();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

**My FireStore Database Structure**
[FireStore database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXOUN.png)

Comment: Please post your database structure

Comment: Added the database structure.. Please help me..

Comment: if you are getting a NullPointerException in your variable task.getresult(), I think you should be sure that you are iterating the variable well.